# The meaning of \@@

Tags: macros

A couple of times in the `latex.ltx` kernel, the macro `\@@` is used. For instance in the definition of `\@next` (l.6222):

```
\def\@next#1#2#3#4{\ifx#2\@empty #4\else
   \expandafter\@xnext #2\@@#1#2#3\fi}
```

I don't see the macro defined anywhere. (Quick searches with e.g. `\let`, `\def`, `\newcommand` with and without star, etc. didn't yield anything meaningful.) I also don't see it in `plain.tex`. I kind of don't understand what `\@next` does because of this macro, and a canonical answer wasn't available on the site yet anyway.

So what does `\@@` mean?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why? If you see `\@next` there as a token, then `\@@` *is* a single token, it's no concatenation. It seems to be used as some sort of delimiter in arguments like `\def\foo#1#2#3\@@#4{..}`.

Comment: @Manuel: I'll delete my comments. You're the TeX expert here obviously

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, no, I'm no expert, really. I meant that I saw no connection to what you said.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't understand the definition of `\@next` without looking also at the definition of `\@xnext` and at an example of usage; the complete code is

```
\def\@next#1#2#3#4{\ifx#2\@empty #4\else
   \expandafter\@xnext #2\@@#1#2#3\fi}
\def\@xnext \@elt #1#2\@@#3#4{\def#3{#1}\gdef#4{#2}}
```

and an example of usage is at line 5963

```
\@next\@marbox\@freelist{\global\count\@marbox\m@ne}%
   {\@floatpenalty\z@
    \@fltovf\def\@currbox{\@tempboxa}\def\@marbox{\@tempboxa}}%
```

The second argument to `\@next` should be a parameterless control sequence (due to the `\ifx` test and the following `\expandafter`). The macro `\@freelist` is such a macro, used in connection with the float queues, and it is updated when a float is started or floats are flushed with `\clearpage`. Its definition at startup is

```
\@elt\bx@A\@elt\bx@B\@elt\bx@C...\@elt \bx@R
```

that is, it lists the insertion classes pertaining to floats (here `...` denote similar tokens).

If `\@freelist` contains nothing, the fourth argument is delivered; otherwise

```
\expandafter\@xnext\@freelist\@@\@marbox\@freelist{\global\count\@marbox\m@ne}\fi
```

remains on the input stream. So, assume `\@freelist` is not empty and, for the sake of simplicity, it is the same as at startup. The `\expandafter` makes TeX see

```
\@xnext\@elt\bx@A\@elt\bx@B\@elt\bx@C...\@elt \bx@R\@@\@marbox\@freelist{\global\count\@marbox\m@ne}\fi
```

Note that, in order for this to work, the first level expansion of the second argument to `\@next` *must* begin with `\@elt`. What's `\@elt`? It's just a token usually defined to be `\relax`, which is used to store ordered lists of tokens in the form `\@elt<token1>\@elt<token2>...` that allows for list manipulations.

Now the definition of `\@xnext` comes into play. It has a complex parameter text that can be described as follows:

1. `\@elt` is expected just after the command
2. `#1` means an undelimited argument, so just one token or a braced group, because it's immediately followed by `#2`
3. `#2\@@` means a delimited argument, that is, TeX will substitute `#2` with everything up to (and excluding) the first `\@@` token it finds;
4. `#3` and `#4` are undelimited arguments (the same as for `#1` applies).

In the context of delimited arguments, the delimiter tokens need not be defined; TeX looks for the *exact* sequence of tokens and control sequences are considered equal only if their *names* are the same.

The delimiters are removed from the input stream as part of macro expansion. So in this particular case, `\@elt` is found and the search for the following arguments can start (`\@elt` will be removed); argument `#1` is `\bx@A`; argument `#2` is

```
\@elt\bx@B\@elt\bx@C...\@elt \bx@R
```

and arguments `#3` and `#4` are `\@marbox` and `\@freelist` respectively.

Expansion of `\@xnext` makes all that code be replaced by

```
\gdef\@marbox{\bx@A}\gdef{\@freelist}{\@elt\bx@B\@elt\bx@C...\@elt \bx@R}
```

The two definitions are performed, which in particular shows how `\@marbox` becomes equivalent to `\bx@A` (the first insertion class) and `\@freelist` is updated, essentially removing the first item. The dangling `\fi` remaining disappears by general TeX rule (the expansion of `\fi` is empty, provided it resulted from expansion of a previous conditional, which in this case was the `\ifx` we started with).

The token `\@@` is used in a very similar way, that is, as a pure delimiter, in the auxiliary macros for the loop functions `\@for` and `\@tfor`.

Comment: So the expanded form of parameter 2 of `\@next` contains, after expansion, three tokens, the first being `\@elt` unconditionally?

Comment: @1010011010 The expansion of argument `#2` to `\@next` *must* start with `\@elt`. That's the only requirement.

Comment: So in the definition parameters `#1#2` can be a single token? Or will TeX first expand this until one token remains or something? `\expandafter` expands only once...

Comment: @1010011010 I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: `\expandafter\@xnext #2\@@...` precedes `\def\@xnext \@elt #1#2\@@...`, so I thought parameter 2 in `\@next` contained `\@elt<token1><token2>` in expanded form ?

Comment: @1010011010 It doesn't matter whether the definition of `\@xnext` precedes or follows tha definition of `\@next`. What's necessary is that `\@xnext` is defined when `\@next` is *called*.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, just the next line defines a macro that uses `\@@` as a delimiter:

```
\def\@next#1#2#3#4{\ifx#2\@empty #4\else
   \expandafter\@xnext #2\@@#1#2#3\fi}
\def\@xnext \@elt #1#2\@@#3#4{\def#3{#1}\gdef#4{#2}}
```

So it seems to be used as a delimiter (like `\@nil` or `\relax` in traditional LaTeX or quarks in expl3, `\q_stop`, etc.). I don't know it there's an additional idea behind `\@@` (like there's when someone uses quarks or `\relax`s, etc.).

Comment: In this case, whether `\@@` has a definition or not is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I meant I didn't know if there was an *idea* when using it (not referring to its definition); opposed to it just being a random (easy recognisable) token.

Comment: The delimiter `\@@` is used also in other places, notably in the auxiliary macros for `\@for` and `\@tfor` loops, but not only.

Comment: @egreg You seem to understand the macro, unlike me. Care to post an answer explaining it? E.g., why doesn't it matter that `\@@` exists as a definition or not?

Comment: @1010011010 It works as a delimiter, it's gobbled by the macro when grabbing arguments. So it doesn't matter at all. Say you define `\def\foo#1\bar#2\baz{..}`, then using `\foo whatever{even with braces}\bar[And even more)\baz`, it doesn't matter what `\bar` and `\baz` mean (if they mean anything at all) they are gobbled when `\foo` is grabbing arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If you get the documentation for the array environment (say `texdoc array`) then it refers to `\@@`serving as an argument delimiter — see, for example, page 9 of the documentation from TeX Live 2014 (and other distributions). The `sources2e` documentation (say `texdoc sources2e`) has `\@@` in its index but does not explicitly mention its usage (at least anywhere I could see). Perhaps this is a standard TeX technique ?

Comment: using a delimiter *is* a standard tex technique.  the delimiter need not be `\@@`; it doesn't even need to be in the form of a command -- `\commandname#1 #2<` will do as well (observe that this example contains two delimiters).  it's not part of the "latex prescribed definition mechanism" because the author of latex decided that bracing arguments was a better approach.